# Phrase for "able to concentrate for long periods of time"

Tags: phrase-requests, epithet-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that describes someone who is able to concentrate and work for long periods of time without taking a break. An example would be a computer programmer who can sit in front of the computer and write code for hours without getting distracted or needing to take a break.

**Edited to clarify**:
I am looking for a word/phrase that describes the positive attribute of someone who is able to do this (along the lines of "diligent" or "assiduous"), not a phrase that describes someone who is actually doing it.

Example: "John is responsible, diligent, and ___. "

Comment: When you edit, please add an example sentence with a blank.

Comment: John is responsible, diligent, and focused when demanded.

Comment: "not easily distracted"??

Comment: Audacious or tenacious. Maybe the latter.

Comment: "in his element"?

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but I would like to propose some more hints for someone who can.  Driven, Efficient, Self-motivated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focused

> Directing a great deal of attention, interest, or activity towards a particular aim:
>
> Darren knows what he wants and he's very focused.
>
> He seems to be very focused on the new challenge.
>
> The need for more focused research

Oxford Dictionary of English

Comment: This is a good option, but means more "focused on a goal" as opposed to "focused on whatever he is doing"

Comment: Being focused does now carry extra meaning about the subject of which the focus is on. I don't think there is such a word that describes being focused on an activity specifically.

Comment: @leo - agreed, "focused" is easily understood to mean "on whatever the task is" when not modified with an actual task.

Answer (score 0):

How about [persevering](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persevere)

> to persist in a state, enterprise, or undertaking in spite of counterinfluences, opposition, or discouragement